# How to deal with related composite foreign keys with one of them being nullable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

Here are the relevant schema parts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Alarm" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE "AlarmSensor" (
  "alarmId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Alarm"("id"),
  "sensorId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Sensor"("id"),
  PRIMARY KEY ("alarmId", "sensorId")
);

CREATE TABLE "AlarmUser" (
  "alarmId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "Alarm"("id"),
  "userId" INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES "User"("id"),
  PRIMARY KEY ("alarmId", "userId")
);

CREATE TABLE "AlarmOccurrence" (
  "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "time" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  "alarmId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "sensorId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "acknowledgedAt" TIMESTAMP NULL,
  "acknowledgedByUserId" INTEGER NULL,
  -- Both FKs share the same alarmId, but I want acknowledgedByUserId to be initially null
  FOREIGN KEY ("alarmId", "sensorId") REFERENCES "AlarmSensor"("alarmId", "sensorId"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("alarmId", "acknowledgedByUserId") REFERENCES "AlarmUser"("alarmId", "userId")
);
```

Look, I'm not a database design expert. So if you think I could improve this somehow, I would love to learn how to do it! Anyways, can I create a new AlarmOccurrence with acknowledgedByUserId initially set to null? Currently, to create a new AlarmOccurrence I have to connect/create an user to fill the alarmId/userId foreign key. I'm guessing that's because alarmId is not nullable.

Edit: I found out this is an ORM problem. I can insert to the table as desired using raw SQL. But in the application code both FKs are marked as required. I will open an separate issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What is stopping you? What does your research show? What exactly do you mean by "create [...]"? Please for code questions give a [mre].

Comment: @philipxy I'm using [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/) for database access. It's marking the `acknowledgedByUserId` as required. By 'create' I mean Insert, in ORM terms

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please act on my earlier comment. You haven't clarified "create" or what is stopping you from doing it, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- define the foreign keys with the default option `MATCH SIMPLE`

  Then, if any of the columns on which a foreign key is defined is NULL, the foreign key is not enforced.
- define the foreign keys with `MATCH FULL`

  Then either all foreign key columns must be NOT NULL or all must be NULL (in which case the foreign key is not enforced).

Read the documentation of [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) for more.

Note to the aspiring database designer: don't ever use double quoted identifiers. Otherwise you will have to use the double quotes in all your SQL statements, which makes you life harder than necessary.

Comment: But I defined `acknowledgedByUserId` as NULL. So, If `MATCH SIMPLE` is the default, it should be working, but I can't create a new `AlarmOccurrence` without filling `acknowledgedByUserId`. Could this be a ORM bug then?

Comment: To respond to your note: I'm using double quotes because it's a [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/) naming convention. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot insert a row with NULL `acknowledgedByUserId`? What is the error message?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I found out this is an ORM problem. I can insert to the table using raw SQL as desired, but Prisma is marking both FKs as required. I will open an separate issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Standard defines "matching type" for partially nullable foreign keys. It has three possible values.

- Match **Full**: The whole FK must be null or not null. If not null, it's enforced against the referenced table.
- Match **Partial**: If parts of the FK are null, then non-null columns are validated against in the referenced table; there must be at least one row in the referenced table with those values. This mode is not implemented by PostgreSQL, though it's mentioned in the documentation.
- Match **Simple**: If there are nulls in the FK it's accepted but not validated against the referenced table.

In your case, it seems that "FULL" may be right choice for you. You can see the syntax at [PostgreSQL ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altertable.html).